# Understanding the difference between a Viewer and a ViewingApplication

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

This question is related to my previous question ([How to implement a Forge Autodesk model-aggregating viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56562608/how-to-implement-a-forge-autodesk-model-aggregating-viewer) ). My current viewer is based on the http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/ tutorial, and there's a part of the code I don't understand :

```
var options = {
  env: 'AutodeskProduction',
  getAccessToken: getForgeToken
};
var documentId = 'urn:' + urn;
console.log(documentId)
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function onInitialized() {
  viewerApp = new Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication('forgeViewer');
  viewerApp.registerViewer(viewerApp.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D);
  viewerApp.loadDocument(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
});
```

The previous code, as far as I understood, initialize the viewer. However I don't figure out what kind of object `viewerApp` is. Indeed :

- It's an `Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication`, so according to the documentation it should not have any specific method ( https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication.html ).
- It wraps an `Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D` so it should make sense if it calls the `loadDocumentNode` method ( https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D.html#loadDocumentNode ), however it only calls `loadDocument`, and I can't find this method in the documentation, plus I can't call other `Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend to refrain from using `ViewingApplication` as it's being deprecated (albeit ployfill available for legacy support) in the upcoming Viewer v7.* (GTA next week).

Go with `Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D` or `Autodesk.Viewing.Private.Viewer3D` and see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/tutorials/basic-viewer/) on how to initialize and load a model.

And see here for [doc](https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/Autodesk.Viewing.Document.html) on `AAutodesk.Viewing.Document.load` (equivalent to `loadDocument`).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It solved my problem, now I've a basic viewer to work on !